# vba formulaR1c1 concatenate

Tags: vba, excel

I want a cell that has this formula to calculate two difference times.

EX:

6/22/2016  10:19:26 AM ,
6/24/2016  10:33:57 AM

How to i write this in vba?
I tried to do in R1C1:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(RC[4]-RC[3])" & " days, " & "Hour(RC[4]-RC[3])" & " hours, " & "Minute(RC[4]-RC[3])" & " minutes and " & "Second(RC[4]-RC[3])" & " seconds"
```

It's showing Application-defined or object-defined error.

I want the result like this:

```
2 days, 0 hours, 14 minutes and 31 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the formula you are feeding to excel is

```
=INT(RC[4]-RC[3])days, Hour(RC[4]-RC[3]) hours, Minute(RC[4]-RC[3]) minutes and Second(RC[4]-RC[3]) seconds
```

You could call the `CONCATENATE` function. So your code would look like this.

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(INT(RC[4]-RC[3]), "" days, "", Hour(RC[4]-RC[3]), "" hours, "", Minute(RC[4]-RC[3]), "" minutes and "" ,Second(RC[4]-RC[3]), "" seconds"")"
```

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I modified the wording to reflect the fact that it is not the only way

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the quotes in the actual formula need to be escaped (in VBA) and there are some quotes misplaced.

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(RC[4]-RC[3]) & "" days, "" & Hour(RC[4]-RC[3]) & "" hours, "" & Minute(RC[4]-RC[3]) & "" minutes and "" & Second(RC[4]-RC[3]) & "" seconds""
```

Comment: I was working on this and swear I did exactly what you did and would get errors.  Forgot the dang `"""` at the end and only had one.

Comment: @ScottCraner - it took me a few tries as well :) Doing grunt work to answer questions!